# Can you please explain this concept and how it works?

Tags: memory

[image: Picture taken from the solidity language docs- Introduction of smart contracts page]

I would like to clear my doubt that when caller and called contract are same. Then the memory will get a new initialization right? or is it a different case.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your own contract's external functions (recursively) by `this.functionName`. If you inspect `msg.sender` in that subsequent call, the result is the that contract's address. Since it's an external call, a new memory range is allocated.

Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract A {
    event Addr(address);

    function myA() view external returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function test() public {
        emit Addr(this.myA());
    }
}
```

If you call the function `test`, you see it emits the same contract address.